# itextsharp layer/overlap/stamp pages with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a couple PDFs that I want to layer together.

```
________
|PDF A  |
|_______|

________
|PDF B  |
|_______|
```

PDF A is just a pdf with a background image. I want to overlay PDF B (which is just text) on top of PDF A so that the text is in the foreground and the background image is behind it.

I've ran across so many examples that merge documents together, but none that can stamp a page on top of another page.

I found an example that adds a text watermark which is a similar funtion, but it's not working for me because i think the methods only handle text.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("\\server\itextsharp.dll")
$pdfReader = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader]::new("C:\Users\profilename\Desktop\testdir123\template_background.pdf")
$statementfile = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader]::new("C:\Users\profilename\Desktop\testdir123\test_withText.pdf")
$stream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new("C:\Users\profilename\Desktop\testdir123\test_output.pdf", [System.IO.FileMode]::Create, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write)
$pdfStamper = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper]::new($pdfReader, $stream)

for($i = 0; $i -lt $pdfStamper.Reader.NumberOfPages; $i++)
{
    $pdfData = $pdfStamper.GetOverContent($i+1)
    $baseFont = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont]::CreateFont([iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont]::HELVETICA, [iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont]::WINANSI, [iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont]::EMBEDDED)
    $pdfData.BeginText();
    $pdfData.SetColorFill([iTextSharp.text.pdf.CMYKColor]::LIGHT_GRAY)
    $pdfData.SetFontAndSize($baseFont, 80)
    $pdfData.ShowTextAligned([iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte]::ALIGN_CENTER, $statementfile, 300, 400, 45)
    $pdfData.EndText();
}

$pdfStamper.Close()
$stream.Close()
$pdfReader.Close()
```

I want to find a solution similar to this which can handle my needs listed above. Is there any method or function or any other means to do this with using only powershell/dll?

I was also trying a c# solution trying to run it inside powershell but I'm not C# savy so I'm really failing hard there.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("\\server\itextsharp.dll")

$bg_file = '"C:\Users\userprofile\Desktop\testdir123\STAC_V7.pdf"'
$fg_file = '"C:\Users\userprofile\Desktop\testdir123\test.pdf"'
$out_file = '"C:\Users\userprofile\Desktop\testdir123\test-Output.pdf"'




$code = @"
using System;
namespace test
{

    public static bool MergePDFs(List<string> lststrInputFiles, string OutputFile, out int iPageCount, out string strError)
    {
        strError = string.Empty;

        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(OutputFile);
        PdfDocument pdfDocumentOut = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);

        PdfReader pdfReader0 = new PdfReader(lststrInputFiles[0]);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument0 = new PdfDocument(pdfReader0);
        int iFirstPdfPageCount0 = pdfDocument0.GetNumberOfPages();
        pdfDocument0.CopyPagesTo(1, iFirstPdfPageCount0, pdfDocumentOut);
        iPageCount = pdfDocumentOut.GetNumberOfPages();

        for (int ii = 1; ii < lststrInputFiles.Count; ii++)
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader1 = new PdfReader(lststrInputFiles[ii]);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument1 = new PdfDocument(pdfReader1);
            int iFirstPdfPageCount1 = pdfDocument1.GetNumberOfPages();
            iPageCount += iFirstPdfPageCount1;
            pdfDocument1.CopyPagesTo(1, iFirstPdfPageCount1, pdfDocumentOut);
            int iFirstPdfPageCount00 = pdfDocumentOut.GetNumberOfPages();
        }

        pdfDocumentOut.Close();

        return true;
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp 
iex "[test]::MergePDFs($bg_file,$fg_file,$out_file)"
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? “Not working” is not much to work off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that makes it.

Please take an important note why no one does BACKGROUND, but many do FOREGROUNDs:
Most default PDF printer (`Microsoft Print To PDF`) makes PDFs with non-transparent background.

As a result, this background-from-user-document covers your background-from-template image. You can not strict requirements to every PDF comes from user.

Otherwise, overlay PDFs (watermarks) are very popular, because you can make a well-prepared PDF for covering user's PDF, and you don't care about it's transparency.

[image: Example]

```
Add-Type -Path "S:\SCRIPTS\iTextSharpTest\itextsharp.dll"
$inFgPdfFilename = 'S:\SCRIPTS\iTextSharpTest\FG.pdf'
$inBgPdfFilename = 'S:\SCRIPTS\iTextSharpTest\BG.pdf'
$outPdfFilename = 'S:\SCRIPTS\iTextSharpTest\OUT.pdf'

# This is memoryStream we will write to. This memoryStream might be saved to file later.
# You can use [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($outPdfFilename) directly instead, but if something fails during works with Pdf, you'll have an empty unusable file.

$tempMs = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new() 

 # Open two readers: for Foreground (Fg, main text) and for Background (Bg)
$inPdfFgReader = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader]::new($inFgPdfFilename)
$inPdfBgReader = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader]::new($inBgPdfFilename)

# Create Stamper. Stamper will put stamps on $inPdfFgReader pages and put stamped pages to $tempMs
$stamper = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper]::new($inPdfFgReader, $tempMs) 

# Get page 1 from background file as stamp tool (template).
# Page numbers in Pdf start from 1.
$bgPage = $stamper.GetImportedPage($inPdfBgReader, 1)

# Loop through pages of main (Fg) document and apply stamp tool ($bgPage) template to each page
# Page numbers in Pdf start from 1.
for ($i = 1; $i -le $inPdfFgReader.NumberOfPages; $i++)
{
    # There are layers in PDF page.
    # Think that each page is 3 sheets of paper - Under, Middle and Over
    # Get link to lowest (Under) layer of $i-th page. 
    # Our content remains on `middle` layer
    $pdfContentByte = $stamper.GetUnderContent($i) # There is also GetOverContent for watermarks that must cover pages

    # Add contents of our stamp tool (page 1 from Bg) to lowest (Under) layer's of $i-th page at (X,Y) coordinates = (0,0).
    # Our main content remains on `middle` layer, and we put background to layer UNDER middle layer.
    $pdfContentByte.AddTemplate($bgPage, 0, 0) # Add template at X,Y
}

# Close everithing to make files get released and buffers flushed into MemoryStream
$stamper.Close()
$stamper.Dispose()
$inPdfFgReader.Close()
$inPdfBgReader.Close()
$inPdfFgReader.Dispose()
$inPdfBgReader.Dispose()

# Write output file and close MemoryStream
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($outPdfFilename, $tempMs.ToArray())
$tempMs.Close()
$tempMs.Dispose()

# > [iTextSharp.text.Version]::GetInstance() | FL
#
#
# Product    : iTextSharp™
# Release    : 5.5.13.1
# GetVersion : iTextSharp™ 5.5.13.1 ©2000-2019 iText Group NV (AGPL-version)
# Key        :
```

---

For foreground just change `GetUnderContent` to `GetOverContent` and prepare a transparent PDF.

P.S. I made it with Descounted [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/) version. It is not recommended to use it anymore and there is recommendation to move to [iText7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/)

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you

Comment: One question, if my foreground is say 10 pages, and my background is only 1. How would I modify this to handle putting the background on all 10 foreground pages? I'm researching this but if you happen to know I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @shadow2020 smth like that ( updated code - enclosed into `for` loop )